# ASP.NET, GridView, BoundField, HeaderText Translation

Tags: asp.net, globalization

Im having a problem with the HeaderText not being translated when i have definied a new resource file.. all other text do translate but not the HeaderText, even the TemplateField.HeaderText gets translated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    PageSize="25" GridLines="None" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" 
    meta:resourcekey="GridView1Resource1">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" 
            meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Skapad" 
            meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Skapad av" 
            meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource3" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Till" meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="Till" 
                    meta:resourcekey="lblToResource1" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hplPopup" runat="server" Text="Öppna" 
                    meta:resourcekey="hplPopupResource1"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle CssClass="foot" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selected" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, where *TitleHeaderText* would be the name of the resource (example code, untested):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:TitleHeaderText %>" 
        meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1" />
```

[Here's an explaination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) of how to access web page resources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not in your code, Is in your ".resx" file.

A "TemplateField" does not contain an attribute ".Text" it contains a ".HeaderText" attribute, as oppose to the most common ".resx" reference that only reference labels and other elements that contain Text="MyText" attributes

**For example!**

`yourResxReference.Text` <-- Must Be --> `yourResxReference.HeaderText`

[Here is an example from actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdJvB.png)

```
txtEmployeesToRemoveListCommentResource1.ToolTip
```

**Should be**

```
txtEmployeesToRemoveListCommentResource1.HeaderText
```